# Wince Socket exception on asynchronous HTTP request

Tags: c#, sockets, httpwebrequest, windows-ce

I am writing a WinCE app in C# that makes an HTTP POST to an APACHE server residing on my network. Because of some network issues (I am guessing), I get the following exception in the managed code

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException occurred
    Message="A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond"
    ErrorCode=10060  
    NativeErrorCode=10060
    StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.ConnectNoCheck(EndPoint remoteEP)
       at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
       at System.Net.Connection.doConnect(IPEndPoint ep)
       at System.Net.Connection.connect(Object ignored)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

This exception isn't always thrown, but when it is thrown, my app fails to connect to the server AT ALL. Repeated connection attempts don't help in reconnecting either. The only thing that helps is closing and re-deploying the app.

I can't catch the exception because its inside of managed code. Is there any way to circumvent this and close all socket connections to my server and re-initialize them? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message looks a bit misleading ("*connection* attempt failed because the *connected* party") but I think it means your hardware is communicating with the server, but the server is not accepting the connection on the TCP level.

A problem I could think of is "hanging" connections, causing the server to reach the maximum number of concurrent connections and to stop accepting new ones.

Although it's just a guess, you might want to check the apache log if you can to see if you can find out if the server reports anything, and perhaps try restarting apache as soon as the problem occurs again. If that helps, you still need to find the cause of course.